# Do I have to ask another question?

Tags: discussion

[Can a cat drink human milk?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/can-a-cat-drink-human-milk)

This question seems basically asking what I'm going to ask: "can a cat drink breast milk from human?", but it seems unclear what actually is OP asking.

I want to edit the question, but not sure how to do it without modifying it too much from OP's original intent. **What should I do? Do I have to ask another question or edit this one?**

Comment: You can ask a new question and link the old one. Then you explain why yours differ from the old one (i.e. not clear question, so not the answers you look for).

Answer (score 1):

It is a really weird question and I'd invoke "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." as per the [help pages](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

There's all sort of 'strangeness' in feeding a cat milk from a human being and practically as a (former) pet owner I don't think that's a 'normal' problem of pet ownership.

I'd say not to bother, and as is, the question is *very* hard to fix, and the problems are localised to the original poster.

Comment: As a mum I can tell you, that you may feel bad by throwing away breast milk you have stored for "in case of..." but do not want to feed your baby anymore. To give it to a cat would be an obvious thought for me. (You can pump the milk and freeze it, i.e. to enable dad to feed the baby at mummy's free evening. But there are time frames you need to use it up in )

Comment: @Allerleirauh that's actually what happened to my friend - she threw away her milk, but felt bad. In my area there are a lot of kittens can't nurse to their mom for a lot of reason, so I thought if it is possible to feed them "human milk" in an emergency.

Comment: I doubt you'll get an objective answer, though. This is not exactly a common topic for scientists, vets or animal welfare organizations, which would usually provide the most trustworthy answers. Don't know how much value any anecdotal answer has.

Comment: @Elmy maybe it is possible to compare cats milk with humans milk... First search shows, that human milk has much less proteins than cat milk, lactose and fat seems to be the same amount.